# Unable to upload wordpress plugins

Tags: plugins, themes

I try to upload WordPress Plugin from my computer for my theme in localhost, but I receive Following Error

> The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

I am also changed

> upload_max_filesize = 64M in my local wamp server php.ini file

Comment: Restart WAMP and then try uploading the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Make sure you've set up proper `upload_max_filesize`. You can use `phpinfo` to check / verify.

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

- More info. on [phpinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)

(2) You may also need to increase your max post size. Look for this line in your php.ini file `post_max_size` and increase it as well.

- You need to restart Apache for the changes to take effect.
- Retry to upload.